# Add prevent default to on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that says if this elements doesnt have class run funciton...

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow:not(".disabled")', altSaws);
```

this works fine, but my `e.preventDefault` is within altSaws function and so when the element has class disabled, upon click the user is taken to the top of the page, is there any other way I could do this?

hope this makes sense?

Comment: Either you can have another handle which will call the prevent default... or have the condition check within the existing handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 solutions

Either move the default preventing call to a separate handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow:not(".disabled")', altSaws);

function altSaws() {
  //no need to prevent default here
}
$(document).on('click', '.arrow', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

or handle the `disabled` condition within `altSaws`

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow', altSaws);

function altSaws(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    return;
  }
  //your existing logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function altSaws is what is missing in the question, but it should start like this:

```
function altSaws(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...     
}
```